# "TorchScript requires source access in order to carry out compilation" error after converting script to exe

Tags: python, pytorch, pyinstaller, torch, torchvision

I am trying to convert the script to exe using pyinstaller
the script is using the inception resnet v1 model from facenet_pytorch by tim esler found [here](https://github.com/timesler/facenet-pytorch)

after running the converted script exe the following [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XCA7.jpg) appears:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "site-packages\torch_utils_internal.py", line 46, in
>   get_source_lines_and_file
>
> File "inspect.py", line 955, in getsourcelines
>
> File "inspect.py", line 786, in findsource
>
> OSError: could not get source code
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "Fcenet-Pytorch\Test Rec2.py", line 1, in
>
> File "", line 983, in _find_and_load
>
> File "", line 967, in
>   _find_and_load_unlocked
>
> File "", line 677, in _load_unlocked
>
> File
>   "c:\users\jorda\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py",
>   line 623, in exec_module
>       exec(bytecode, module.**dict**)
>
> File "site-packages\facenet_pytorch__init__.py", line 1, in
>
> ```
> # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
> ```
>
> File "", line 983, in _find_and_load
>
> File "", line 967, in
>   _find_and_load_unlocked
>
> File "", line 677, in _load_unlocked
>
> File
>   "c:\users\jorda\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py",
>   line 623, in exec_module
>       exec(bytecode, module.**dict**)
>
> File "site-packages\facenet_pytorch\models\inception_resnet_v1.py",
>   line 1, in
>
> File "", line 983, in _find_and_load
>
> File "", line 967, in
>   _find_and_load_unlocked
>
> File "", line 677, in _load_unlocked
>
> File
>   "c:\users\jorda\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py",
>   line 623, in exec_module
>       exec(bytecode, module.**dict**)
>
> File "site-packages\torch__init__.py", line 367, in
>
> File "", line 983, in _find_and_load
>
> File "", line 967, in
>   _find_and_load_unlocked
>
> File "", line 677, in _load_unlocked
>
> File
>   "c:\users\jorda\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py",
>   line 623, in exec_module
>       exec(bytecode, module.**dict**)
>
> File "site-packages\torch\distributions__init__.py", line 112, in
>
> File "", line 983, in _find_and_load
>
> File "", line 967, in
>   _find_and_load_unlocked
>
> File "", line 677, in _load_unlocked
>
> File
>   "c:\users\jorda\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-
>   packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in
>   exec_module
>       exec(bytecode, module.**dict**)
>
> File "site-packages\torch\distributions\von_mises.py", line 54, in
>
> File "site-packages\torch\jit__init__.py", line 1287, in script
>
> File "site-packages\torch\jit\frontend.py", line 164, in get_jit_def
>
> File "site-packages\torch_utils_internal.py", line 53, in
>   get_source_lines_and_file
>
> OSError: Can't get source for . TorchScript requires  source access in order to
>   carry out compilation, make sure original .py files are available.
>   Original  error: could not get source code
>
> [4348] Failed to execute script Test Rec2

some solution I've found online is to downgrade torchvision to 0.2.2.post3
but that would prevent the original script from running

I've tried all kinds of hiddenimports the same error still occurs

any idea how to fix it?

System:
Windows 10

Python 3.7

torch 1.5.0

torchvision 0.6.0

pyinstaller 3.6

facenet-pytorch 2.2.9